# h2 database test maven

Tags: java, database, testing, maven-2, h2

### Testing java application using H2 database 1.3.169

I'm testing my app in two different ways.

1. In-memory database is created in a separate process from the application. I start H2 console and create database from scripts. All tests pass.
2. In-memory database is created in the same process with the application when application start. All tests pass in Intellij IDEA 11.3. Using Maven 2 for testing some tests fail(create, update, delete for the one entity, expected dataset does not match with result). It seems as database wasn't updated. It doesn't happen every time, sometime build is successful. All tests are verified, all works on Oracle and DB2.

What could be the cause of the problem?

Comment: how you configure H2 db? Does it have parameter `DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1`

Comment: Without pom.xml files structure of your project and configuration of h2 it's hard to guess what's wrong.

Comment: @user1516873 connection url- jdbc:h2:mem:mydb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-
#1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;MVCC=true;MODE=ORACLE.

Comment: @khmarbaise unfortunately i can't add my pom.xml, configuration is default except connection parameters.

Comment: sorry, right connection url-jdbc:h2:mem:mydb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;MVCC=true;MODE=ORACLE

Comment: @shprotova are you really need `DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE` parameter? Try to remove it and rerun tests.

Answer (score 2):

THis situation occurs when you configure connection to your in-memory H2 DB by default, for example: `dbc:h2:mem:test`

In that case DB exist until he has at least one active connection. When last connection closed, DB also closed. Depends of what you use/re-use connection (maybe pooling) and running test delays, you can get racing conditions and get unexpected results.

It can be fixed with connection parameter `DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1`, what mean db was closed only when VM died.

This is helphul link http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#closing_a_database

Comment: Thank you for answer, but i tried to add this connection parameter. No results. May be something else?

Comment: Depends of your tests configuration. For example, does some tests relay on changes, made by different tests. Maybe maven run tests in different order. What test framework you're using? junit? testng? Does you have explicity define test suite in xml?

Comment: and try remove `DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE` parameter.

Comment: All tests don't relay on changes, made by different tests. Test framework - dbunit 2.4.8.Test order doesn't matter, because all tests are independent from each other. All test resources explicitly defined in xml.

Comment: Try remove DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE parameter - i tried. No results. All fun - now all tests pass the last 5 times. Parameters were not changed. No changes at all.

Comment: And naybe it is just a bug with MVCC. As described in documentation `MVCC is disabled by default. The MVCC feature is not fully tested yet.`

Comment: I agree with you. I thought about it.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late for you to answer your question. Probably this might help.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver" />
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;INIT=create schema if not exists test\;runscript from 'classpath:scripts/sample.sql';**DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1**"/>
```

in addition to it try to add below properties

```
<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>      
<prop key="hibernate.connection.release_mode">auto</prop>
```

which will create schema every time server starts and drop when done.